# How are the Planes in 4e connected?

Tags: dnd-4e, planes

In DnD 4E, the planes are listed as being:

1. The Astral Sea
2. Elemental Chaos
3. The "World", being the "normal realm".
4. Feywild, being the "magical realm".
5. Shadowfell, being the "underworld".
6. Far Realm

So my questions are:

- How are the planes connected?
- How do you depart one plane and get to another?
- Can you explain the Astral Sea and Elemental Chaos further? Is the Sea just like space with little planets, or "dominions", floating around? And that's where the gods live and the Primordials live in the Elemental Chaos?

Comment: I suspect question #3 should be asked separately. The first two can neatly make this a question about how the planes are connected and travelled between, which are two questions that it is _very good_ to ask together. The other can ask more detail about the Astral Sea and Elemental Chaos. (Or if that's a request for more detail from my own answer that I deleted - it sounds like it could be? - you could leave it as a comment on that answer.)

Comment: The related/resulting question by doppelgreener: [What are the planes of D&D 4e? Where did they come from, and how are they connected?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/41174/33569)